# C++ Need to convert BYTE * data from my Webcam to ID2D1Image * for ID2D1Effect::SetInput method for crossfade effect

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I am working on a C++/CLI program using Win32 Media Foundation and Windows Forms. I was able to get my USB webcams data into a `BYTE*` array in C++ and pass the data to my managed code to display in a picturebox.

Now I want to be able to do a crossfade between 2 cameras, but the code I wrote in C++ doesn't do it smoothly. I am experimenting with the Direct2D ID2D1 crossfade effect to see if it would look any better.

Apparently the `ID2D1Effect` interface `ID2D1Effect::SetInput` method wants the data as a `ID2D1Image*`. I could really use some help to figure out how to convert a frame of RGB32 webcam data pointed to by a `BYTE*` pointer to `ID2D1Image*`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CrossFade.h
#pragma once

#include <comip.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d2d1effects_2.h>


#pragma comment(lib,"d2d1.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"dxguid.lib")

class CrossFade
{

    ID2D1Factory* pD2DFactory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* pRT;

public:

    //Data in my webcam class
    BYTE * srcData = nullptr;
    BYTE * dstData = nullptr;

    //Methods

    CrossFade(HWND hwndPgm, int iWidth, int iHeight);

    ~CrossFade();

    void Draw(ID2D1Image* pBitmapSrc, ID2D1Image* pBitmapDest, float dWeight);

};



CrossFade.cpp

#include "CrossFade.h"

CrossFade::CrossFade(HWND hwndPgm, int iWidth, int iHeight)
{

   HRESULT hr = S_OK;
   pD2DFactory = NULL;
   pRT = NULL;

   D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pD2DFactory);

   //hwndPgm references the picturbox handle. I may need to change this to a panel handle according to some posts.

   hr = pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), 

   D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwndPgm, D2D1::SizeU(iWidth, iHeight)), &pRT);

}

CrossFade::~CrossFade()
{

}



void CrossFade::Draw(float dWeight)
{

    if (srcData == nullptr || dstData == nullptr) return; //Data not ready

    //I know this is incorrect, I'm just trying to indicate I need the BYTE* data to be converted to ID2D1Image* data
    ID2D1Image* pBitmapSrc = srcData;
    ID2D1Image* pBitmapDest = dstData;
    
    CComQIPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> spDeviceContext = pRT;

    CComPtr<ID2D1Effect> spCrossFadeEffect;
    spDeviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1CrossFade, &spCrossFadeEffect);

    // set source and destination bitmaps
    spCrossFadeEffect->SetInput(0, pBitmapSrc);
    spCrossFadeEffect->SetInput(1, pBitmapDest);

    spCrossFadeEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CROSSFADE_PROP_WEIGHT, static_cast<FLOAT>(dWeight));

    spDeviceContext->DrawImage(spCrossFadeEffect);

}
```

Once this is working, I would also like to figure out how to use animation to create a smooth transition. if I include `afxanimationcontroller.h` I get an error `WINDOWS.H` is already included. MFC apps must not `#include<Windows.h>`.

Is there something other than MFC I could use to animate the crossfade? I'm not using MFC otherwise.

Comment: You need to use ID2D1DeviceContext::CreateBitmap https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1devicecontext-createbitmap(d2d1_size_u_constvoid_uint32_constd2d1_bitmap_properties1_id2d1bitmap1) with the parameter corresponding to your in-memory bitmap. An ID2D1Bitmap(1) *is a* ID2D1Image.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I've been trying variations of this command all day. The only example I can find starts with a Render Target like 'hr = renderTarget->CreateBitmap(D2D1::SizeU(iWidth, iHeight), (const void*)srcData, iWidth * 4, D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)), &srcBitmap);' I can never figure out how to create a render target for something that doesn't physically exist. When I try beginning with 'hr = CreateBitmap(' it thinks I'm doing something else with different parameters.

Comment: "Is there something other than MFC I could use to animate the crossfade? I'm not using MFC otherwise."
You could try to use [AnimateWindow function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You have a device context (`spDeviceContext`) so you can call CreateBitmap. What's the problem with that? if it returns error then enable DirectX debug layer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps  https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/

Comment: spDeviceContext is for the picturebox for the output of the crossfade. I created a HwndRenderTarget pRT for that. Now I need a device context for the input data from the two cameras. A renderTarget doesn't seem right for an input. All I have is a BYTE * pointing at a frame of RGBA pixels from two cameras. How do I create a device context for that? Thank you, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks Jeaninez, I will look at that once I get the basic cross fade working.

Comment: I am not getting anywhere with this. ID2D1DeviceContext::CreateBitmap requires a DeviceContext. As far as I can determine a device is a display adapter which is better suited as a target rather than a source. Is there a way to create a Device and DeviceContext that refers to a space in memory? Then I might be able to create an ID2D1 bitmap from my camera data to use as a source for the crossfade. Please let me know if there is a better way to get a frame of RGB32 camera data in a BYTE * array into an ID2D1Image. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use this function to convert your BTYE* data to a ID2D1Bitmap1 interface which inherits from ID2D1Image.

```
HRESULT CreateBitmap(
  D2D1_SIZE_U                   size,
  const void                    *sourceData,
  UINT32                        pitch,
  const D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 *bitmapProperties,
  ID2D1Bitmap1                  **bitmap
);
```